# Problem executing rails server on port 3000 and using -p

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When trying to run rails server in port 3000 i get

`` in `listen': Address already in use - listen(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE) ``

tried with `lsof -wni tcp:3000` and found nothing. Tried killing ruby processes, used  `ps aux`  to search for similar processes and still nothing.
After all this tries i gave up and ran
`rails server -p 3001`  and actually worked once, but after i stopped the server and tried to start it again, i got the previous error as if -p don't work and i'm still running on port 3000.

Error when running `rails server -p 3001`

````
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 2.7.6-p219) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 1
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 905
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/bin/puma-wild:25:in `<main>'
        8: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/cli.rb:81:in `run'
        7: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:182:in `run'
        6: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/single.rb:44:in `run'
        5: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/runner.rb:156:in `load_and_bind'
        4: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:156:in `parse'
        3: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:156:in `each'
        2: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:222:in `block in parse'
        1: from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:429:in `add_unix_listener'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:429:in `listen': Address already in use - listen(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)```
````

Comment: there should be a pid number inside tmp/pids/server.pid.  kill that process

Answer (score 0):

`kill -9 PID_number` *Type your actual PID number so in your case 905"